# USB disconnecting and reconnecting every 2-3 minutes

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, bios, motherboard

I'm having some flashbacks to last year with an annoying issue on my USB on both the front panel and back I/O. I'm a bit at loss as to what to do next. Would you have suggestions?

**Description of Problem**: USB devices (mainly USB drives) disconnect and immediately reconnect every 2-3 minutes. This started happening after I updated the BIOS from version 4301 to 4602. I already had the issue before version 4301 I believe, but it had been fixed with that update. The issue reappeared now, much worse than before. It basically renders USB keys unusable. This was a known problem at the time, which was supposed to be fixed with AGESA 1.2.0.2, so I'm not sure why it reappeared now...

**Troubleshooting**: I've tried downgrading the BIOS, updating the chipset driver, uninstalling and reinstalling the USB drivers and disabling C-State to no effect.

**Computer Type**: Desktop

**GPU**: RX 5600XT

**CPU**: RYZEN 5 3600

**Motherboard**: ROG STRIX B450-I GAMING

**BIOS Version**: Version 4602

**RAM**: Corsair Vengeance LPX, DDR4, 16GB (2 x 8GB), 3600MHz

**PSU**: Corsair SF600 Platinum

**Case**: NCase M1 V.3

**Operating System & Version**: WINDOWS 10 PRO 19043.1503

**GPU Drivers**: Radeon™ Software Adrenalin 22.1.2

**Chipset Driver**s: AMD B450 Chipset Software 3.10.22.706

I also note that there seems to be a recent resurgence in these types of problems since early 2022,  [although the other are on MSI boards compared to my ASUS](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/msi-b450-tomahawk-max-ii-usb-port-connection-sometimes-disconnect-and-reconnecting.370990/).

Comment: To determine if the issue is in BIOS/UEFI or in Windows OS, boot and run from USB using another OS, such as Linux (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows, for example) or Windows RE/PE (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference?view=windows-11), such as a recovery USB created by Macrium Reflect. If either of those work flawlessly, then fix the issue in Windows, not BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the suggestions. The issue appears to be resolved, although I am not sure what did it, so I'll just detail my steps here:

- I checked in the BIOS the voltage of both 5v and 12v rails, they were well within error margins.
- Since most answers suggested something in relation to power supply, I disconnected and reconnected all cables plugged into the PSU, as well as moved the front I/O cable further from PSU cables. It was tangled in one of them and I feared some sort of interference.
- I also disconnected and reconnected the front I/O USB cable.

After all that, the issue seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

These symptoms can be caused by electrical power issues within USB sub-system, e.g. by a damaged cable. If you have a USB multi meter, you could connect that into your PC and connect the USB drive into the meter. Then check whether voltage and/or current decrease for a short while. If you do not have an USB multi meter, you may try with a device that consumes lots of energy (for an USB-A socket preferable over 0.75A, for USB-C socket you may go up to 3A at 5V) and quickly reacts on power glitches, so e.g. a fan is not suitable (because of inertia it continues to rotate for many seconds even after complete power failure) while a bright LED or an electric magnet is suitable. A loading mobile phone might signal a short power issue or might gracefully ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a software to determine the status of your 5v and 12v rails.  They need to be + or - 5%.

To determine if your power supply is enough.

Then I would begin by replacing as many cables as possible with new cables capable of the max power draw of 5a.  This may take hours of searching to find.

Depending on how many USB devices you have and how much power they consume you may have to have some of them on external powered hub.